# Is there a reason the ratio of the Bohr speed to the speed of light approximates the fine structure constant?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, physical-constants

$$\frac{Bohr_s}{c} \approx \frac{1}{137} \approx \frac{1}{137.035999084} 
 = \alpha$$

Where $Bohr_s$ is the speed of the electron in the Bohr model of the hydrogen atom and $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant.

What, if anything, explains $\frac{Bohr_s}{c} \approx \alpha$?

Comment: Since the supplied (and accepted) answer contains the accepted definition of the Bohr speed, I reduced the question to just in terms of the Bohr speed, c and $\alpha$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same. First, we need the correct formula for the Bohr speed:
$$v_B = \sqrt\frac{k_ee^2}{m_e a_0}$$
Substituting $k_e = 1/4\pi\epsilon_0,$
$$v_B = \sqrt\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0m_e a_0}$$
Substituting the Bohr radius $a_0 = 4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2/e^2m_e$
$$v_B = \sqrt\frac{e^4}{16\pi^2\epsilon_0^2 \hbar^2}$$
$$v_B = \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 \hbar}$$
Finally, we use the definition of the fine-structure constant $\alpha = e^2/4\pi\epsilon_0 \hbar c$
$$v_B = \alpha c$$
$$\alpha = \frac{v_B}{c}$$
In fact, if you look at the [history of the fine-structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#History), you'll see that the ratio of the Bohr speed and the speed of light was the original definition of this constant.

Comment: If dark energy increases a0 then  the fine structure constant will decrease and there will be fewer  virtual photons emitted  weakening the electromagnetic force. Since this doesn't seem to have happened over billions of years then surely this proves dark energy doesn't stretch space locally.

Comment: Thanks.  That history is particularly relevant.